# Which version of ChromeDriver should I install when working with the Silenium Python library with Google Chrome version 122.0.6261.70?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Which version of ChromeDriver to install if Google Chrome version is 122.0.6261.70 If there is no such version on ChromeDriver? I tried to install the latest version of ChromeDriver, but it turned out to be version 122.0.6261.69. Although my version is 122.0.6261.70. What should I do in this case,  install the old version of Chrome? I would be grateful for any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJBnA.png)

I tried to install the latest version of ChromeDriver, but it turned out to be version 122.0.6261.69. Although my version is 122.0.6261.70. What should I do in this case,  install the old version of Chrome? I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can import ChromeDriver directly in the code, there is no need to download the 122.0.6261.70 ChromeDriver version.

First you install the library:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Then import the required libraries and initialize the driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(link)
```

You can find the source of the solution [here](https://pythonexamples.org/python-selenium-open-chrome-browser/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a variety of reasons, [link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].